# In a React App, should the country-state-city package go into the backend or frontend?

Tags: reactjs, web, geolocation, frontend, backend

The `country-state-city` package is heavy in size. Can someone list the precise size of the package?

Design 1:

Load the package in the frontend APP

Design 2:

Load the package in the backend APP and then have the frontend ping the backend to send the appropriate State/City list upon detecting a change to the Country/State?

Which is the correct design in such scenario?

The full APP will be for mobile as well as web browsers.

Comment: how the package size affect your app?

Comment: Well, it takes up more space on the client side?

Comment: i found this https://css-tricks.com/how-to-worry-about-npm-package-weight/ if the size of your app is a matter you can use some tools to analyze. also you can try the package both front and back end to see whats the difference. let us know your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to add `country-state-city` to my frontend and the production bundle size increased from 1.1 MB to 16.6 MB.

So the approach to return the data from the backend looks much more useful.